# User Access rights for menu in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop, drop-down-menu

Here is my problem. I have two tables like this and a PHP code.

**TABLES**

```
    menu
    ====
    m_id    menu_name   parent_menu_id  menu_order  menu_url    status 
    1       M1          0               1           #           1
    2       M2          0               2           #           1
    3       S1          1               1           #           1
    4       S2          1               2           #           1


    user_rights
    ===========

    user_id         rights
    1               1,2,3,4
    2               1,2,3
```

**CODE**

```
<?php
    $get_user_id = $_GET['id']; //  user id will be 1 or 2
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("booksdb") or die(mysql_error());
    $get_access_query = mysql_query("SELECT rights FROM user_rights where user_id='".$get_user_id."'");
    $fetch_access_list = mysql_fetch_row($get_access_query);
    $get_access_list = $fetch_access_list[0];
?>
<div id='mymenuclass'>
    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach (explode(',', $get_access_list) as $n) {
            $get_main_menu_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu where m_id='".$n."' and parent_menu_id='0' order by menu_order");
            $get_main_menu = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_main_menu_query);
        ?>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span><?php echo $get_main_menu['menu_name']; ?></span></a>
    <ul>
        <?php 
        $get_sub_menu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu_master where parent_menu_id='".$get_main_menu['m_id']."'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $get_sub_menu )) {
        ?>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='<?php echo $row['menu_url']; ?>'><span><?php echo $row['menu_name']; ?></span></a></li>
        <?php } ?>   
    </ul>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The above query works fine for first level menu. But when it comes to sub menu it is displaying all the sub-menus. Don't know where I went wrong.

For ex: `user_id = 2` is allowed to access only menus 1,2 and 3. But my above codes gives permission for 1,2,3 and 4.

How can I restrict it?

Any help?
Thanks,

Kimz

NOTE:

my code is really pathetic. it will confuse experts like you. but my requirement is explained well above. help me out and i can reward you back ;)

Comment: so if I have access for parent menu id = 1, you will give me the submenus from it, by this query, aren't you? `SELECT * FROM menu where m_id='".$n."'`

Comment: no not lik that. each and every menu should be checked with the user_rights table. each and every menu(including submenus) will be authenticated

Comment: @RoyalBg i have edited my php code again. please check

Comment: my code is really pathetic. it will confuse experts like you. but my requirement is explained well above. help me out and i can reward you ;)

Comment: The question I have is still the same :) `$get_sub_menu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu_master where parent_menu_id='".$get_main_menu['m_id']."'");`, so if I have access to `main_menu_id` 1 the query will be `SELECT * FROM menu_master where parent_menu_id=1`, and it will retrieve ALL submenus. You should have additional condition for user rights in this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I will suggest to normalize your database, because there is something wrong with these user access coma separated rights and menu holding. Second, to stop using mysql_* lib (however, in the example below I have not changed it) as Pinoniq said. Third, not to mess the queries inside the HTML, because it's easily to get lost in the translation, and cannot find the problem.

Now, the problems I see here are:

You, for example, has following schema:

User ID: 1
Main Menu ID: 1
Child Menu ID: 5
Child Menu ID: 8
Child Menu ID: 50
User rights: 1, 8, 50

You want your user, to have access to Main menu 1 but only to its child menus 8 and 50, without `5`

```
$get_main_menu_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu where m_id='".$n."' and parent_menu_id='0' order by menu_order");
```

This one will turn into:

```
SELECT * FROM menu where m_id='1' and parent_menu_id='0' order by menu_order
SELECT * FROM menu where m_id='8' and parent_menu_id='0' order by menu_order
SELECT * FROM menu where m_id='50' and parent_menu_id='0' order by menu_order
```

Since 8 and 50 are CHILD MENUs second and third query will not return result, because parent_menu_id is not ZERO. Only first one will return results.

Later

```
$get_sub_menu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu_master where parent_menu_id='".$get_main_menu['m_id']."'");
```

will result in

```
SELECT * FROM menu_master where parent_menu_id=1
```

Which will return THREE results: 5, 8 and 50, because you DID NOT TELL: `give me the sub menu from parent id 1 AND which user has rights in.

You need to return to the check where the rights were fetched and apply `AND id = "fetchedRecordsFromUserRights"`

which should turn into:

```
SELECT * FROM menu_master where parent_menu_id=1 AND id = 1; // 0 records
SELECT * FROM menu_master where parent_menu_id=1 AND id = 5; // 0 records because 5 is not in RIGHTS
SELECT * FROM menu_master where parent_menu_id=1 AND id = 8; // 1 record
SELECT * FROM menu_master where parent_menu_id=1 AND id = 50; // 1 more record
```

The following code I will give you is trying to do this with splitting in functions, so you won't need to fetch rights two time. However, I do not guarantee it's perfectly workable, because I did not tested it, and if it is not, you should do it yourself, to check which function returns wrong values.

Have in mind, that you do not need the RIGHTS in array. MySQL has `IN()` operator, so if you have fetched string `1, 8, 50` you can do

```
SELECT * FROM menu_master where parent_menu_id=1 AND id IN (1, 8, 50);
```

Which will return 2 records, for 8 and 50.

This is the code I have rewritten for you

```
<?php
    $get_user_id = $_GET['id']; //  user id will be 1 or 2
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("booksdb") or die(mysql_error());

    /**
     * 
     * @param int $get_user_id
     * @return string
     */
    function getMenuRights($get_user_id) {
        $get_user_id = intval($get_user_id);
        $get_access_query = mysql_query("SELECT rights FROM user_rights where user_id='".$get_user_id."'");
        $fetch_access_list = mysql_fetch_row($get_access_query);
        $get_access_list = $fetch_access_list[0];
        return $get_access_list;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param int $get_user_id
     * @return array
     */
    function getUserMainMenus($get_user_id) {
        $get_user_id = intval($get_user_id);
        $rights = getMenuRights($get_user_id);
        $get_main_menu_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu where m_id IN ($rights) and parent_menu_id='0' order by menu_order");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_main_menu_query)) {
            $results[] = $row;
        }
        return $results;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param int $parent_menu_id
     * @param int $get_user_id
     * @return array
     */
    function getUserChildMenu($parent_menu_id, $get_user_id) {
        $parent_menu_id = intval($parent_menu_id);
        $get_user_id = intval($get_user_id);
        $rights = getMenuRights($get_user_id);
        $get_sub_menu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu_master where parent_menu_id='".$parent_menu_id."' AND id IN ($rights)");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $get_sub_menu )) {
            $results[] = $row;
        }
        return $results;
    }
?>
<div id='mymenuclass'>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach (getUserMainMenus($get_user_id) as $get_main_menu): ?>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span><?=$get_main_menu['menu_name']; ?></span></a>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach (getUserChildMenu($get_main_menu['m_id'], $get_user_id) as $row): ?>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='<?=$row['menu_url']; ?>'><span><?=$row['menu_name']; ?></span></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>   
    </ul>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are trying to solve with php should actually be solved at database level.
You are storing an array of rights as plain text. why?
Now every time you need to check access to a certain menu item you need to fetch all the rights, explode it into an array, ... expensive.

So, let's solve this problem on database level. We do this first by writing everything down in human readable text. Implementation comes after that.

We have a user (stored in table user). And every user can have zero or more menu-access-rights. So this is a many-to-many relationship. *Many* users can have *Many* menu-access-rights.

So, we have a table `users` and we have a table `menu` and a table `menu_rights` (imo, menu_access would be a better name).

The `menu_rights` table links a user to a certain `menu.item`. this gives us 2 columns for the `menu_rights` table begin `user_id` and `menu_id`

So now, if you would like to get all menu_items that $currentUser has access to you let the database handle all the logic instead of having to write that hideous explode everywhere:

```
SELECT menu.* FROM menu,menu_rights WHERE menu.id = menu_rights.menu_id AND menu_rights.user_id = $current_user_id
```

Now, SQL handles all te access rights logic. Neat, because SQL also keeps track of all the access rights. One single query to retrieve all menu items you have acess to.

Then, on an other note. Don't ever use your code in production. just don't.
Here are some reasons why:

- Navigate to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php and
  read the big fat red Warning.
- Never ever trust anything coming from the client ($_GET, $_POST,
  ...). Make sure [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) can't get in

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the suggestions already provided, if you know that there will only ever be a handful of 'rights' then you could store these in bitwise fashion:

```
privilege _id 
1             
2
4
8
```

In this design, a user with a score of 3 would enjoy privileges 1 & 2, while a user with a score of 15 would enjoy all privileges.